# how can i add css style for a div when i clicked on a button in another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'am trying to add some css styles for a div text, when I clicked a button in another div

**here is my html code**

```
<div class="row" id="target">
  <h2>{{txt}} </h2>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <button my-dir>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

**my js code**

```
.directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      console.log(elem); 
      elem.bind('click', function (e) {
        console.log("coming");
        elem.find('#target').css({
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        })    

        // angular.element(e.target).siblings('#target').addClass('clr');
      });

    }
  }
});
```

my problem is when I clicked on button in one div css styles has to apply for the another div using directive, I tried something like above but didn't worked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elem` will refer to the `button`. So `elem.find('#target')` will look for `#target` inside `elem`

You can do like this

```
elem.bind('click', function (e) {
        $('body').find('#target').css({
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        })    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if your element id is unique and non changed then you can simplify it as below

```
 elem.bind('click', function () {
         $('#target').css('backgroundColor','red');
 });
```

elem.find will find all div with id contains 'target', try to use unique id's for all div changes. It will help you.